# Convert SharePoint online Workflow 2013 to Power automate. Can we have Transition to stage?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, power-automate

I have this as part of a classic SharePoint online 2013 workflow, where there is a "transition to stage" :-

[image]

and i want to redesign it using Power Automate, so what is the equivalent action to the "Transition to stage" inside Power Automate? is using sub-flows the option to go with?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know there no "Transition to stage" equivalent in Power Automate. In general "Transition to stage" is something like GOTO concept in programming languages, which is [not necessary/not recommended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto).
You can redesign logic in your SharePoint 2013 workflow or use sub-flows (as you suggested).